# HUEY alternative for rq.get_current_job()

Tags: django, redis-server, django-rq, python-huey

We are migrating from **[rq](https://github.com/rq/rq)**, **[django-rq](https://github.com/rq/django-rq)** to **[HUEY](https://github.com/coleifer/huey)** for one of our **Django** project as **[rq](https://github.com/rq/rq)** is causing trouble running in **Windows** machine due to **[fork](https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/226)** issue.

There was a function in `rq` named `get_current_job()` which actually returns the current instance of running job no matter where ever it's been called:

```
from rq import get_current_job

def update_job_status(status):
    job = get_current_job()  # even though no arguments are passed it's returning the current instance of job which is running in the memory.
    BackgroundJob.objects.filter(jobid=job.id).update(status=status)
```

I know that I can pass the Huey's task as an argument to `update_job_status` but the problem is it's been called from hell lot of the functions/nested functions and it's very difficult to change all the codes.

**Is it possible to achieve something similar in Huey?**

Comment: Hi, did you manage to deal with this problem?I am in exactly the same situation at the moment and would be very grateful for any help. Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I was never succeeded using Huey and finally had to drop my plan for windows migration. ☹️